# Spring Boot Question 3.1.2 (upgrading) exclude of DataSourceAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

We are upgrading fromm Spring Boot 2.7.10 to 3.1.2.

When starting one of the modules we got the error that a datasource must be configured.

Below is the class as working in 2.7.10, but it looks like the exclude attribute is not working properly at `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`

Is this a known issue and how can I fix this?

This is the code

```
package nl.the.application;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.EnableMongoAuditing;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class TheClientApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TheClientApplication .class, args);
    }


}
```

Starting the applications ends with

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'dataSource' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'dataSource' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Spring Batch requires a datasource as of Spring Batch 5 which is included in Spring Boot 3. So the exclude does work as there is no datasource configured (which is what the error is telling you) but as Spring Batch now needs one it will fail. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#job-repositoryexplorer-configuration-updates